# Magento 2.2.x : Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, theme, frontend, custom-theme

I'm pretty fresh to Magento and been playing around with Magento 2.2.6 on a MAMP setup.

Can anyone recommend any trustworthy resources for building a theme from the ground up? I am also interested in courses if anyone can recommend any good courses. I checked Udemy but there aren't many Magento courses.

Answer (score 4):

- You should first start by understanding basic structure of Magento if you are a beginner, for that you can read from  [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html).
- Check [here](https://u.magento.com/front-end-developers), you can take some help of basics of frontend development.
- I also suggest to read some blogs of experts suggested [here](https://extait.com/blog/10-best-magento-bloggers-from-whom-you-need-to-learn/)
- Even you can attend bootcamps arranged by Magento community itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty good official magento documentation for theme development and frontend customization at magento devdocs here -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html

I recommend **installing grunt** and putting your website on **developer mode** for starting any frontend customization or theme development.

If you are looking for something particular you can always post your queries here in magento stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you for the link and Grunt suggestion...I actually prefer Gulp, but same idea. And yes, I already put the site in development mode.